# Align contents within div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to form a header for a website. There is a div, within this div there is a logo and links.

I cannot figure out how to center the logo/links vertically and horizontally within this div. I suspect it has something to do with the links not playing nice.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="all.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <img id="Logo" src="images/.png" alt="">
            <div id="nav">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="#.html">text</a>
                <a href="#.html">text</a>
                <a href="#.html">text</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
    </footer>

    </body>



</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    background-color: #383838;
    background-image: url("images/bkg.png");
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0px auto -25px;
}
footer {
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#header {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#Logo {
    width: 230px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
}
#nav {
    width: 450px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav a:link {
    font-size: 26px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle as well.

Comment: A fiddle would really help.

Comment: I couldn't get the fiddle to properly demonstrate my problem..

Answer (score 0):

I'v made a small change(only for the css) with your code, ** white borders are used to clarify the element positions(you can remove them)**, now that vertically aligned.

```
#Logo {
border: 1px solid #fff;
top: 10px;
left: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 90px;
position: absolute;
color: white;
}

#nav {
margin-top: 10px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
width: 450px;
}
```

And for horizontally aligning another tiny edit:

```
#Logo {
border: 1px solid #fff;
top: 10px;
left: 50%; /* Notice the 50% */
margin-left: -45px; /* Should always be half the logo width. */
height: 50px;
width: 90px;
position: absolute;
color: white;
}

#nav {
margin-top: 10px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
width: 450px;
}
```